# c++ how to load a heterogeneous collection from file

Tags: c++, serialization

I want to make a heterogeneous collection, that is able to load itself up from a file.

I have this code:

```
void HeterogeneousCollection::load(std::istream& is) {

    is >> size;

    for (size_t i = 0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        int id;
        is >> id;
        switch (id) {
        case 0:
        {
            Line* line = new Line;
            line->load(is);
            this->add(line);
        }
        case 1:
        {
            Circle* circle = new Circle;
            circle->load(is);
            this->add(circle);
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't think of any other ways to solve this problem, but as it turns out, it doesn't work at all.

The only error I get is a runtime access violation at a later time when I want to access data that I assumed is correctly loaded by this piece of code.

Line and Circle stem from a parent object Shape.

Heterogeneous collection's save function:

```
void HeterogeneousCollection::save(std::ostream& os) const {
    os << size << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        os << (*this)[i].getId() << std::endl;
        (*this)[i].save(os);
    }
}
```

Shape's save and load function:

```
void Shape::save(std::ostream& os) const
{
    os << id << std::endl;
    color.save(os);
    pos.save(os);
}

void Shape::load(std::istream& is)
{
    is >> id;
    color.load(is);
    pos.load(is);
}
```

Line's save and load function:

```
void Line::save(std::ostream& os) const 
{
    Shape::save(os);
    P1.save(os);
    P2.save(os);
}

void Line::load(std::istream& is) 
{
    Shape::load(is);
    P1.load(is);
    P2.load(is);
}
```

the file I'm trying to read from, produced by a previous call of HeteroStore's save():

```
2 //size of store
0 //id of a Line
0 //R of color of a Line
0 //G of color of a Line
0 //B of color of a Line
23 //X of position of a Line
12 //Y of position of a Line
23 //X of a point of a Line
12 //Y of a point of a Line
49 //X of another point of a Line
6  //Y of another point of a Line
1  //id of a Circle
0 //R of color of a Circle
0 //G of color of a Circle
0 //B of color of a Circle
10 //X of position of a Circle
10 //Y of position of a Circle
10 //radius of a Circle
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the add() function is incrementing size every time a pointer is added to the heterogeneous collection, so size (initialized non zero at the beginning of the load function) will not represent the size of the store correctly, and every function of the store that relies on it will be broke as hell.
For example, in the save() function the for cycle will run too much, and non existing pointers will wanted to be accessed, as the error showed correctly.

The solution:

```
void HeterogeneousCollection::load(std::istream& is) {

    is >> sizeofotherstore;

    for (size_t i = 0; i<sizeofotherstore; ++i)
```